# UL unexpected height with .clearfix class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using clearfix class to clear the floating element. But it behaves strange with the `ul` element. It is adding height to the `ul`, which seems to be taken from the `.sidebar` `ul` element. I googled a lot but I did not find any explanation or solution.

JsFiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/2cfGV/3/

JsFiddle full page view:
http://jsfiddle.net/2cfGV/1/embedded/result/

```css
 .clearfix2:before, .clearfix2:after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
}
.clearfix2:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `display: table`. Using `display: block` requires additional properties to be set: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Comment: Hm, I had this working in your fiddle (guess I should have saved it). I'll take another look at it.

Comment: I don't think it's actually the clearfix not working. I think this is an issue of only floating one div. If you add `float: left` to `.second`, the clearfix works. http://jsfiddle.net/2cfGV/4/ I will say this is some strange behavior.